# babel7 config for newer node targets fails on `import` statements

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, babeljs

When building my `node` api with webpack and babel and node v12.13, I'm getting this error:

```
Module build failed (from /../node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):TypeError: /../src/handler.js:
Property name expected type of string but got null
```

This seems to be related to ES6 `import` statements in the source files.

Below is the config I have ended up with.
Based on this, the only thing that makes it work is setting `{ targets: { node: 6 }}` but I need to set target to v12.

I haven't found a relevant discussion. What could be the reason for this issue?
This is a package inside a `yarn workspace`, but I think this shouldn't matter.

.babelrc: (located in api package root, same result with a `.babelrc.js` or `babel.config.json`)

```
  comments: false,
  presets: [
    [
      '@babel/preset-env',
      {
        targets: {
          node: 'current'
        }
      }
    ]
  ],
  plugins: [
    '@babel/plugin-transform-runtime',
    '@babel/plugin-transform-regenerator',
    '@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs',
    '@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread',
    'source-map-support'
  ]
```

webpack.config.js:

```
const path = require('path')
const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals')
const slsw = require('serverless-webpack')
const webpack = require('webpack')

module.exports = {
  entry: slsw.lib.entries,
  target: 'node',
  mode: slsw.lib.webpack.isLocal ? 'development' : 'production',
  optimization: {
    minimize: false
  },
  performance: {
    hints: false
  },
  devtool: slsw.lib.webpack.isLocal ? 'eval-source-map' : 'none',
  externals: [
    nodeExternals({ whitelist: ['workspace-package-b'] }),
    nodeExternals({
      modulesDir: path.resolve(__dirname, '../../node_modules'),
      whitelist: ['workspace-package-b']
    })
  ],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.graphql$/,
        loader: 'graphql-tag/loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: ['imports-loader?graphql', 'babel-loader']
      }
    ]
  },
  output: {
    libraryTarget: 'commonjs2',
    path: path.join(__dirname, '.webpack'),
    filename: '[name].js',
    sourceMapFilename: '[file].map'
  },
  plugins: [new webpack.DefinePlugin({ 'global.GENTLY': false })]
}
```

Relevant package.json:

```
(dependencies)
"babel-runtime": "^6.26.0",
"core-js": "^3.6.4",
(devDependencies)
"@babel/core": "^7.9.0",
"@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread": "^7.4.4",
"@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs": "^7.9.0",
"@babel/plugin-transform-regenerator": "^7.8.7",
"@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.9.0",
"@babel/preset-env": "^7.9.0",
"babel-jest": "24.9.0",
"babel-loader": "8.1.0",
"babel-plugin-source-map-support": "^2.0.1",
"jest": "24.9.0",
"webpack": "4.19.1",
"webpack-node-externals": "^1.7.2"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the gist is this:

I had initially added these plugins because jest complained about seeing an `import`.

```
    '@babel/plugin-transform-runtime',
    '@babel/plugin-transform-regenerator',
    '@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs'
```

But then I realized that this now broke my normal webpack build.

The two issues related to this seem to be:

- how webpack relates to [jest](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/webpack):

> webpack 2 offers native support for ES modules. However, Jest runs in Node,
>    * and thus requires ES modules to be transpiled to CommonJS modules.

- the breaking upgrade of `jest` to v24 which [stopped injecting `regenerator-runtime`](https://jestjs.io/blog/2019/01/25/jest-24-refreshing-polished-typescript-friendly#breaking-changes) (and babels `preset-env` assuming it's there)

The following `.babelrc.js` resolves this issue for me:

```
/*
 * webpack 2 offers native support for ES modules. However, Jest runs in Node,
 * and thus requires ES modules to be transpiled to CommonJS modules.
 *
 * Reads:
 * https://jestjs.io/docs/en/webpack
 * https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/6229
 *
 */
const configByEnv = isTest => {
  // https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-env#targets
  // "Sidenote, if no targets are specified, @babel/preset-env will transform
  // all ECMAScript 2015+ code by default."
  const targets = isTest ? {} : { node: 'current' }

  const addPlugins = isTest
    ? [
        '@babel/plugin-transform-runtime',
        '@babel/plugin-transform-regenerator',
        '@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs'
      ]
    : []

  return {
    comments: false,
    presets: [['@babel/preset-env', { targets }]],
    plugins: [
      ...addPlugins,
      '@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread',
      'source-map-support'
    ]
  }
}

module.exports = api => {
  const isTest = api.env('test')

  return configByEnv(isTest)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

that form of `.babelrc` config file is deprecated, instead of that use the one babeljs recommends `babel.config.js`, with this "form" if u wanna call it like that, there is one cool feature. you get a param that has quite a few tricks you can use.

... BTW you are missing @babel/cli, @babel/runtime @babel/core, babel-core@7.0.0-bridge.0

```js
    "use strict";

    module.exports = function (api) {
      const {NODE_ENV} = process.env;

      api.cache(()=>NODE_ENV)
      api.env()

      if (NODE_ENV === "development") {
         api.async();
      }

      return {
    plugins: [],
    presets: []
      }
    }
```

Comment: Unfortunately all this doesn't change any aspect of the result. (What do we need `babel-core` and `babel-core@bridge` for?)

Comment: Reading [here](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/config-files#6x-vs-7x-babelrc-loading) I don't think `.babelrc` is really deprecated, but it behaves differently from 6 to 7.

Comment: @bebbi sorry, I got fat fingers babel-core is not needed, just `babel-core@7.0.0-bridge.0`